# I cannot access a server using ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to access server using ssh from my ubuntu terminal but it responds an error says:

```
/bin/bash: Too many open files in system
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The machine has run out of file descriptors.

Comment: Did you look at any of the [228,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2Fbin%2Fbash%3A+Too+many+open+files+in+system) that google returns when searching for your error message?

Comment: I would still be interested to know how to recover a machine in such a state, for which I have no physical access.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem while connecting to the server.  The solution is:

Connect that server using the super user root password and use this command:

```
    lsof | wc -l
```

It will show you how many files are opened in servera.

And to solve this, kill the application and restart it.

```
    sysctl -a | grep file-max
```

This command gives you system capacity.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem "Too many open files in system", please check the open files using the below command.

```
ulimit -n
```

It will display the open files.

Then increased the limit by going through limits.conf file which is available in the location `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Now add the below content in the file "limits.conf".

```
soft nofile value
hard nofile value
```

The value should be the based on the RAM of the system.

Comment: Please learn how to format posts.